# Managing TestNg suite from Jenkins parameterized build

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testng

I'm running my tests in Jenkins and Maven and have different test suites in several TestNG.xml files.
Now I manage them directly in pom in this way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>Testing_Fuzzy_Logic.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            <suiteXmlFile>Testing_ACL.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But I'd like to be able to select a specific test suite when start a Jenkins build. And I'd like all the suites to be included to the build as default if I did not select a specific one. So my question is:

What  is the proper way to write all my TestNG.xml files in Jenkins parameters and send them to pom file to ask Maven use them when running tests?

Something like this:

Jenkins variable:

[image]

Set it to pom file somehow:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved by an example above. At first there was an error in file name and it confused me. I fixed it and my example works okay now.

**So one of solutions is**: a string TEST_NG_XML parameter which is added to parameterized Jenkins build. All test suites are set there and separated by comma by default. When needed, any of them can be removed (See examples above).

But if there are any other solutions, I'll be delighted to see them.

Answer (score 0):

On jenkins, you can pass top level maven goals in following format

```
test -DargLine="-DTest_NG_XML=src/test/resources/testng.xml"
```

In this way , you are passing the value of your Test_NG_XML variable while running the maven test phase.In general execute following maven goal on jenkins.

```
-DargLine="-Dparameter=value"
```

Answer (score 0):

> test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/resources/testng1.xml,src/test/resources/testng2.xml

How can one be sure the precedence of execution of test suites passed this way?

I was facing the same issue, I have split it into separate Jenkins builds with each passing separate suite, to be absolutely sure certain suite runs before the other.
I would like to simplify it, possibly passing this way as indicated above... but did you try the order of execution? Thanks